# Sampler array gives different result when accessed with a constant instead of a variable

Tags: arrays, linux, opengl, glsl, amd-processor

I'm having weird behavioural issues in a piece of shader code. When I open it with a variable it always gives me the first texture it references, but when I open it whith a simple constant, it gives me the correct textrue.

So this works:

```
final=texture(texShadowMap[curid], coords);
```

And this doesnt:

```
  if(curid==0){
        final=texture(texShadowMap[0], coords);
    }else if(curid==1){
        final=texture(texShadowMap[1], coords);
    }
```

Which is really weird, especially since its only broken on amd cards and runs fine on intel and nvidia. Also there are other texture arrays that I can just easily open normally without any problems.

Does anybody have an idea what might cause this? Because it fundamentall doesn't make sense to me.
Are staticly acessed arrays handled diferently? Did I make a fundamental mistake that broke the whole shaders somehow?

Comment: Is 'curid' integer or float? If float, comparing may have precision issues.

Comment: nope, its a uint and the comparing one is the one that works

Comment: Take a look at [non uniform flow control](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Non-uniform_flow_control)

Comment: thanks, ill have a look at it

Comment: yep the problem was that my amd card was older thn my NIvida and didn't support dynamicly linking texture arrays, thanks